# Declaring a variable inline with an assignment c++

Tags: c++, variables, syntax, bitmap, inline

While reading about bitmap processing in C++ I came across this block of code
used for loading a color palette with data taken from a bitmap file:

```
//set Number of Colors
numColors = 1 << bmih.biBitCount;

//load the palette for 8 bits per pixel
if(bmih.biBitCount == 8) {
        colours=new RGBQUAD[numColours];
        fread(colours,sizeof(RGBQUAD),numColours,in);
}
```

where "bmih.biBitCount" is a predefined variable that already has a value.
Why does the author declare numColors to equal 1 then assign the value bmih.biBitCount to that variable in the same line? what exactly does this do and what are the benefits of assigning a variable a value twice inline like this?

Comment: 1 is not assigned to `numColors` as u think

Comment: You really need to get a beginners book on c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the author declare numColors to equal 1 then assign the value bmih.biBitCount to that variable in the same line?

He doesn't; he assigns the result of the expression `1 << bmih.biBitCount` to `numColors`.  The assignment occurs last.  `<<` is the [bitwise left shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23).  Think of it this way:

```
//set Number of Colors
numColors = (1 << bmih.biBitCount);
```

Comment: so does (1 << bmih.biBitCount) basically mean "copy the value of bmih.biBitCount into numColors for a bitlength of 1*sizeof(bmih.biBitCount)"?

Comment: @bjh: No. Follow the link about bitwise shift operators.

Answer (score 2):

He doesn't, and this is a case where using `<<` as a "streaming" operator confuses people.

The `<<` and `>>` operators were traditionally bit shift operators, which is their meaning in this case. These operators shift a variable left or right by a number of places. Say we have `x = 0b00001` (and your compiler understands binary notation like that). `x << 2` will give the result `0b00100`.

Comment: `1 << bmih.biBitCount` means 1 shifted left bitwise with 'bmih.biBitCount`, which is, most probably zero. I guess `bmih.biBitCount << 1` would be more appropiate.

Comment: @Lorlin - no it doesn't. 1 will be casted to the type of `numColors`, then shifted left by bmih.biBitCount.

Comment: Yep. And 1 shifted left with n is zero for any n!=0. Isn't?